# iPhone developer doesn't match any valid certificate (Xcode)

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, private-key

Hi I've kind of been cornered by apple here, I submitted a technical support query, one of the free ones thats comes free when you pay into the developer program only to be told that they won't be in the office until after Thanksgiving, a problem I overlooked as I am from Ireland. I really need help on this as I've tried looking in forums and I've tried solutions that were given for similar problems but I still can't crack it.

The screenshot images can be seen on this page..
http://www.heffernanwebservices.ie/blank.html

Here it goes...

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM On trying to build my project "Mulligan IRL" in xcode i get the following error " Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: Cian Heffernan (8ELM27DL8F)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain"

[Screenshot 1]

When I navigate to code signing in the build settings of the project i can see that when I click code signing identity for iphone developer or iphone distribution it has "(no profiles currently match) beside them. I then headed to the keychain access window in utilities and look in certificates and find that both the developer and distribution certificates will not expire until next August and November. Next I headed to the organizer in xcode. I see in provisioning profiles I have 8 profiles there! I don't know why I have so many.(2nd attachment)

[Screenshot 2]

As you can see ONE of the iOS team provisioning profiles will expire in 11days so I just tried to renew that. When I try this I get an error:(3rd attachment)

[Screenshot 3]

I then head to the provisioning portal to see why it wasn't found but I can see the profile. (4th attachment)

[Screenshot 4]

I have no idea why I am getting this error. I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 14):

For certificate to be valid it needs to be associated in your Keychain with a private key. Find the "iPhone Developer..." certificate in your Keychain and see if it's got a private key associated with it.

This can occur when you develop on two or more computers. You need to export the certificate+private key pair from the computer where you generated the private key first. Then import it onto all computers you do development on.

See Apple's [Transferring Your Identities](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG24) for more detailed info.

Answer (score 7):

This could be caused by not having the private key associated with your certificate in your keychain. You can verify this by going to Keychain Access and choosing "Certificates" from the "Category" area at the bottom left. If your developer certificate does not appear when filtering that way, you are missing the private key for it.

If this is the case, you'll have to add your private key to the keychain, or else just reject and re-issue your development certificate with a new private key (you can find steps for this in the provisioning portal.)

Answer (score 0):

a useful link from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6) about the submission process. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I was using AppCode, but for me simply adding a new Keychain via Keychain Access called **iPhone Developer** allowed me to start building in AppCode.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a great article regarding Certificates and Provisioning-Profiles,
with excellent troubleshooting:

**[iOS Code Signing Troubleshooting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html)**

The most useful part I found was regarding cleanup of old provisioning-profiles from Xcode:

"**[Keep Your Profile Library Clean](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG15)**
*...You need to **manually remove provisioning profiles you are not using**,

otherwise, Xcode will reimport potentially old or duplicate certificates into the keychain

and that can cause build errors.*"

And as a weapon of last resort, you can use this procedure:
**[How do I delete/revoke my certificates and start over fresh?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6)**